# Return length of strings in array with ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm a beginner to programming and I was given this problem to solve with ruby:

Given an array containing some strings, return an array containing the length of those strings. You are supposed to write a method named 'length_finder' to accomplish this task.

I wrote:

```
def length_finder(input_array)
    a = [ ]
    input_array.each { |n| puts n.length.to_i }
    a << n
    a
end
```

I got an error undefined local variable or method `n'. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Read up on `map`, the Ruby solution to this is a one-liner.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is an assignment, I won't give a direct answer to your problem.  Instead, I'll show something similar.  Suppose you wanted to create an array consisting of the first character of each word in a given array:

```
def first_char(x)
  x.map {|s| s[0]}
end

y = first_char(["abc", "xyz", "def"])      # y => ["a", "x", "d"]
```

Replace `s[0]` with a suitable manipulation for your problem.

Try this (and your own method) in `irb`, the interactive Ruby environment. Exploring is one of the best ways to learn, and `irb` makes exploring easy.

Answer (score 1):

Following your particular approach, it should be

```
def length_finder(input_array)
    a = []
    input_array.each do |n|
        a << n.length
    end
    a
end
```

In your code, you are defining `n` inside a block and printing its size. You don't want to print its size. You want to put it in `a`. You get an error saying it is undefined because you are doing `a << n` *outside* the scope.

Answer (score 0):

First looking at your error, if you look closely, scope of n is only in each block, however you are trying to use it outside it's scope, thats why you are getting this error and second mistake is in a you should be appending n.length, which you want in the output, correct these two and you got a working code:

```
def length_finder(input_array)
    a = [ ]
    input_array.each { |n| puts n.length.to_i
                           a << n.length }
    a
end
```

however, this can be done in one line, using map or inject and the fact that ruby returns the output of last executing statement in a function. I will encourage you the try the one line solution for this.

Comment: thanks! question - why is there a difference in result when I put a line break between n.length.to_i and a << n.length? Doesn't work when the block is on a single line.

Comment: If you want block in one line, just make sure to put a `;` in between them, like this: `input_array.each { |n| puts n.length.to_i a << n.length }`, both will work as same.

Answer (score 0):

what you exactly need is just the following three lines of code:

```
def array_length(input_array)
  length = []
  input_array.each{ |a| length << a.length}
  length
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Map method of Ruby](https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/10/ruby-map-method/) gives one liner solution -

```
def length_finder(input_array)
  input_array.map { |s| s.length }
end
```